# Mysql Full-text search with plus sign

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match-against

I have got a problem.

In my MySql db i have 40000 row in product table. Table has an column called **T9Text**.
One of my row T9Text area is like this:

> UNISNLS106B UNI.SNLS 106B SNLS-106B M.OT. 12V 2 DELİK MOTOR CRAFT TİPİ
>   UNIPOINT 66-205               66205 F02Z-11390-A         F02Z11390A
>   E90Z-11390-A         E90Z11390A F4DZ-11390-A         F4DZ11390A
>   F3VY-11390-A         F3VY11390A E90Z-11390-A         E90Z11390A FORD
>   ESCORT  MERCURY TRACER  FORD

For auto complete process, I run a stored procedure in db. It is like that:

```
SELECT p.Code, 
  p.Name,
  p.`T9Text`,
  MATCH (p.T9Text) AGAINST ('+UNI* +SNLS* +106B*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS SCORE
FROM product p
WHERE MATCH (p.T9Text) AGAINST ('+UNI* +SNLS* +106B*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) >0
GROUP BY p.Name
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
```

Like this, it works great and return just one row.

But i need to write my where condition like this:

```
MATCH (p.T9Text) AGAINST ('+*UNI* +*SNLS* +*106B*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) >0
```

With above code it returns 1877 rows. It is like plus sign doesn't work

```
MATCH (p.T9Text) AGAINST ('+*UNISNLS106B*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) >0
MATCH (p.T9Text) AGAINST ('+*NISNLS106B*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) >0
```

With first query return 1 row, but second query returns 0 row.

So, there is my question: In mysql fulltext search, can not I use +*test* expression?
If not, is there any way to do this? (except LIKE)

Comment: Did you try escaping it as `\+`?

Comment: I think the problem is with `*` -- this can only be used at the end of a word.

Comment: @DannyBeckett  `MATCH (p.T9Text) AGAINST ('\+*NISNLS106B*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` has returned nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Boolean Full-Text Search docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html);

> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. *Unlike the other operators, it should be **appended** to the word to be affected*. Words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.

In other words, boolean search does not support "contains" using the `*` operator.